# C++ Restart Application or re-run 'winapi main'

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making an program and would like to have my program restarted when a person tries to resize the screen.

So far from searching the internet i've found that it's not possible to ''re-run your application'' as with code.

Everyone refers to just close and rerun it, but that's not what i want, i want the code to be doing that.

So i was thinking, can i not re-run winmain? and ' kill ' the current winmain instance in my code, but keep the ''shell (application?)'' active?

this is what i am trying to do:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_SIZE: //Check if the window has been resized
            WinMain(this, this, this, NULL);
            // or restart application code.
            break;
        case WM_PAINT: // we need to paint? lets paint!
            if (DrawUI)
                Render(true);
            else
                Render(false);
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            return DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &pMargin); // extension of window frame into client area
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0); // We need to use this to exit a message loop
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam); // Making sure all messages are processed
            break;
    }
}
```

please see the code under WM_SIZE: that's what im trying to do, but i don't know how to do this correctly, and how to close the previous winmain.

Comment: Restarting the application because the window is resized is extremely annoying behaviour! Do you want to annoy people who are using your program? Do you have a good reason? Every other program doesn't need to do it...

Comment: This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The reason to restart the application is because it is an overlay on an windowed application, and once it resizes the ''drawing from directx(3d)'' does not redraw, i already made it aware to paint/repaint but i can't get it to redraw the correct Crisp way, so since it's and overlay to an existing 3d application i'll just want to restart the application itself, as it's mainly used as a ''Community Moderator'' Tool. and not going to be public to most people.

Comment: You cannot launch a fresh copy of your program simply by recursively calling into what you believe to be the application's entry point. If you want to restart your application, you need to restart your application. Though you're going to get better feedback if you asked about the **real** problem you are trying to solve. Read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Keep in mind that the C++ standard forbids calling main() explicitly. This might be true for winmain as well. That said, I agree with @MikeCAT that this smells like an XY problem.

Comment: I understand that, i don't deny that it's better to ask about the solution @whats wrong with my code@ but the thing is that even i am not sure why it does the thing's as it does, yes i wrote it but my knowledge of C++ is very very limited. i suppose i could write another .exe to mainly restart the application? but i was hoping that maybe somehow this question was going to be possible :)

I did read the XY Problem, which makes sense, but then again; if i knew where the fault was at i would've already fixed it.

Comment: @IInspectable, basicly yes. i think that's the question?

Comment: See [Resizing the app window and the swap chain’s buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj552952(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#6-resizing-the-app-window-and-the-swap-chains-buffer).